# Is there a way to remove all data about a user from Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using authentication in my flutter app. To recreate situations, I delete accounts from the console and log in again. However firebase seems to remember I logged in previously with the account(has a `created on` field in authentication)...Is there away to remove all data from firebase and login as if firebase has never seen the account before?

Comment: is this on web or android or ios?

Comment: iOS and android...

Comment: What exactly are you observing that it "remembers" something about the user?

Comment: You should clear the cache of the app. You can do it by accessing the internal directory and then issue a delete

Answer (score 0):

Delete cache of your own app code :

```
public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
    try {
        File dir = context.getCacheDir();
        deleteDir(dir);
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    } else if(dir!= null && dir.isFile()) {
        return dir.delete();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```